# Understanding the order of tensor application as a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I have a question regarding the application of one tensor to another, $Q(D)$. Let's start with the simplest example, considering the bilinear form $G=G_{ij}(\epsilon^{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j})$ acting on $\vec{v}=v^{k}\vec{e}_{k}$. Thus,

$G(\vec{v}) = G_{ij}v^{k}(\epsilon^{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j})(\vec{e}_{k})$

Can I choose whether to do $\epsilon^{i}(\vec{e}_{k})$ or $\epsilon^{j}(\vec{e}_{k})$? If I can make this choice, what allows me to do so? In a more complex case, my doubts increase. Assuming $Q=Q^{i}\ _{jk} (\vec{e}_{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j} \otimes \epsilon^{k})$ and $D^{ab}\left(\vec{e}_{a}\otimes \vec{e}_{b}\right)$, then

$Q(D) = D^{i}\ _{jk}(\vec{e}_{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j} \otimes \epsilon^{k}) B^{ab}\left(\vec{e}_{a}\otimes \vec{e}_{b}\right)$

In the Eigenchris video lectures, [specifically here](https://youtu.be/9R4vhqvE_jw?si=TMJogW2NLJib9pKY&t=269), he mentions that we can apply D to B in many ways, and this confuses me. For example,

$Q(D) = Q^{i}\ _{jk} D^{ab}\vec{e}_{i} \epsilon^{j}(\vec{e}_{a})\epsilon^{k}( ) \vec{e}_{b}$

I really don't understand why he can choose to do $\epsilon^{j}(\vec{e}_{a})$ when he chose not to apply $\epsilon^{k}$ to $\vec{e}_{b}$, leading to an operation that I don't understand. What is $\epsilon^{k}( ) \vec{e}_{b}$? This couldn't be a tensor product because it comes from the application of Q to D, not the tensor product between Q and D.

Comment: (1) $\epsilon^k()\vec e_b$ is a typo for $\epsilon^k(\vec e_b)$. (2) You get to "choose" in the sense of setting a convention, but once the convention is set you don't get to choose. The most common convention is probably to send the left-most argument to the left-most portion of the tensor product.

Comment: Different ways of applying will lead to different resulting tensors (just try a few examples yourself). Therefore it is not recommended to use such a notation like $Q(D)$ (and i honestly have never seen it before in cases where there is ambiguity).  In the abstract index notation such contractions can be defined without ambiguity or a designated contraction operator with specified indices can be used too.

Comment: @jd27 I tried several examples; that's the reason for my question. Can I perform the operation in any order, or do I need to fix an order? If I can do it in any order, what allows me to do that? Your comment left me with a new question: if the application of a tensor, such as a linear mapping, is different from a tensor product, what is the best way to express that a tensor is acting as a linear mapping ? I learned from Eigenchris's video lectures that it would be written as $Q(D)$ because $Q\otimes D$ has a different meaning. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Amalie "Can I perform the operation in any order, or do I need to fix an order?" Which operation do you mean?

Comment: @jd27 I'm referring to operations of this kind: 

$( \vec{e}_{i} \otimes \epsilon^{j} \otimes \epsilon^{k} )( \vec{e}_{a} \otimes \vec{e}_{b} )$. Is this operation

$\vec{e}_{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j}(\vec{e}_{b})\otimes \epsilon^{k}(\vec{e}_{a})$

 or 

$\vec{e}_{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j}(\vec{e}_{a})\otimes \epsilon^{k}(\vec{e}_{b})$ 

or both?